# SQL Round query

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

Trying to round sales tax and subtotal to two decimal places for my query in SQL. 
Here's my query.

```
    select OrderID
    , ItemID
    , '$' + cast(price as varchar (7)) as [Price] 
    , (price) * 0.06 as [Sales Tax] 
    , (price) * 0.06 + (price) as [Subtotal]

    from ORDER_ITEM
    where price >= (20)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select OrderID
    , ItemID
    , '$' + cast(price as varchar (7)) as [Price] 
    ,convert(decimal(18,2), (price) * 0.06) as [Sales Tax] 
    , convert(decimal(18,2),(price) * 0.06 + (price)) as [Subtotal]

    from ORDER_ITEM
    where price >= (20)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I did actually. I'm new to S/O so my vote doesn't count until I reach a 15 in reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   -- You Can Use ROUND Function to Round Up The Column you want.   
       select OrderID
            , ItemID
            , '$' + cast(price as varchar (7)) as [Price] 
            , ROUND((price) * 0.06,2) as [Sales Tax] 
            , ROUND((price) * 0.06 + (price),2) as [Subtotal]

            from ORDER_ITEM
            where price >= (20)
```